# MPI_Gather not collecting all the blocks into the recv buffer?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a program that uses MPI_Gather from the root process. The non-root processes do calculations based on their world_rank, and the stride.  Essensially chunking out a large array for work to be done... and collected.

However, it 'appears' to go through the work, but the returned data is ... nothing. The collected data is supposed to generate a mandelbrot image.  BUT all that is saved is a black image.  I can't figure out why the gather is not - gathering.??

I do know I can do this via MPI_send/receive, but I really want to understand why this is not working, as it 'appears' to be more efficient. Appreciate any guidance / suggestions.

```
#define MAXPROC 192    /* Max number of procsses */
#define ROOT 0         /* MASTER THRAD*/

#include "TinyPngOut.hpp"

// Image resolution
static const int width = 3840;
static const int height = 2160;

// Dimensions of the Mandelbrot set
static const double xMin = -1.9;
static const double xMax = 0.5;
static const double yMin = -1.2;
static const double yMax = 1.2;
static const int MAX_ITER = 500;
static const int TOTAL_LEN = width * height;

uint32_t mandelbrot(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool save_to_file = true;
    bool printedStart = false;
    char image_pgn[] = "image.png";
    int myRank, numProc;

    // Timers
    double start=MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProc);

    /* Check that we have an even number of processes and at most MAXPROC */
    if (numProc>MAXPROC || numProc%2 != 0) {
        if (myRank == 0) {
        printf("You have to use an even number of processes (at most %d)\n", MAXPROC);
        }
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(0);
    }

    // Compute the size of the workloads for each process
    int stride = height / numProc;
    int firstRow = myRank * stride;
    int lastRow = (firstRow + (stride));
    int arrLen = width * height;

    if (myRank == ROOT){
        printf("STARTING.... mandelbrot calculations with %d\n", numProc);
        printf("CHUNCK_SIZE: %d \n", stride);

        printf("gridSize: %d, stride: %d \n",
            myRank,
            stride);
    }

    // // For each process, create a buffer that will hold a subset of the entire
    // // array
    int *sBuf = new int[arrLen];
    int *rBuf = new int[arrLen];

    /* WORK TO BE DONE,
        There are (total proc - 1) work processes, computing (stride) lines
        static allocation for MPI.  Where world size - 1 process does the calculations
        (ie. if 4 processes, 0 - 3 do the work).
    */ 
    // Store mandelbrot results in image
    for(int y = firstRow; y < lastRow; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            sBuf [x] = (mandelbrot(x, y));
        }
    }

    if (myRank == ROOT) {    /* Process 0 does this */
        
        printf("Process %d is gathering array sBuf from all %d processes\n\n", \
        myRank, numProc);

    }
    /* Gather the array x from all proceses, place it in y */
    MPI_Gather(sBuf, stride, MPI_INT, rBuf, stride, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double elapsed=MPI_Wtime()-start;
        std::cout<< "Rank " << myRank << " took "<< elapsed <<" seconds\n";
```

I have tried diffent data types, including MPI_Data_Type (vector) and declared my own data type, but that had no effect.  I have tried using pointers, and int arrays... with no luck I know that I am missing something simple, just can't see it right now.  I have been working on this for the past day or so.

********************** reply to comment:

Thank you for looking at this... I don't see what you mean.  Both sBuf / rBuf are initialized to arrLen.  The nested for loops are doing the calculations for the mandelbrot, and saving each into sBuf.  The loops are doing tiles of the whole image in slices - called stride (== height/numProc). I initially used an array size of  width * height and if I was using a pointer, used malloc to assign the memory.  So of the gather tutorials showed int ARRAY[SOMESIZE] being used so in this iteration, I was trying pointers again - pretty sure that the intialization is wrong.  Didn't see that last night.

IF I understood the documentation, it seems like the sBuf should be of size stride, and the rBuf should be the whole data struct that is constructed of stride blocks up to the full size of rBuf.

Comment: the value of `stride` looks fishy

Comment: @DávidLaczkó you are correct, sorry

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood about the code, `sBuf` has only meaningful data of size `width` but you are receiving the data of size `stride` in `rBuf` at root from all the processes. This could be the reason for wrong image generated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be writing in shared memory fashion: your sendbuffer is size of the total array, and each process writes into its proper location. That is not how MPI works. The `sBuf` is local to each process; it needs to be of size `stride` and each process writes data starting at location zero. The gather call otherwise looks correct.